# Google Sheets API I cant find the created sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This question is probably simple to answer

I am logged in with my google account, I created a sheet's API project, I created a service account and hooked it up to my python/django project. I successfully created some sheets and put data on it. But where can I find the sheets?

I can get the link to the sheet by the id I get from sh.id, but I think it should be possible to see the sheets in a folder on "my drive" as well? I've been looking for an hour now soon...

Comment: Did you share the sheet created by the service account with your personal account? If not.. why not? The spreadsheet is owned by the account that created it.

Comment: I created it with the app, so I suppose the "service account" owns is somehow. I shared it by link sharing, but the accounts I share it too is not the owner.

Comment: @Viktor How did you go with your Google Sheets problem. Did you resolve your problem, or do you still need help?

Comment: I have not yet found a way to view the created sheets in a drive folder in the browser. I know it was possible one year ago when I did it last time. But now I can't find it.

I can find the individual sheets and open them in the browser if I extract the link programmatically, but it'd be nice to have a way to visually see where everything ends up.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem, the solution that i found to access the sheets i created with the api from the browser app was to add permission programatically with an api call as well.

Here is an example using the python gspread library :

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename="credentials.json")
# sh = gc.create("test_spread").sheet1
perm = gc.list_permissions("THE-SHEET-ID")

print(perm) # this should print a permission dict with only the service account

perm = gc.insert_permission(
    "THE-SHEET-ID",
    "THE-USER-EMAIL-TO-GRANT-ACCESS-TO",
    perm_type="user",
    role="writer", # there are different roles, check the api doc for more.
)
perm = gc.list_permissions("THE-SHEET-ID")

print(perm) # this should print a permission dict with the service account and the newly added account
```